# How to fix Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/text/DocumentException

Tags: java, gradle, itext

I created a console application. This app can generate a pdf. I use itextpdf. I added in build gradle:

```
compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'itextpdf', version: '5.5.10'
```

When I start my program in command line I see a this log:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/text/DocumentException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

When I start my app in IntelliJ it works corretly.

build.gradle :

```
      group 'Harmonogramy'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion = '3.1'
  distributionUrl = "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-$gradleVersion-all.zip"
}

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.34'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbutils/commons-dbutils
    compile group: 'commons-dbutils', name: 'commons-dbutils', version: '1.6'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-csv
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-csv', version: '1.4'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf
    compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'itextpdf', version: '5.5.10'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.opencsv/opencsv
    compile group: 'net.sf.opencsv', name: 'opencsv', version: '2.3'

}

jar {
    archiveName = 'Harmonogramy.jar'

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'Main',
                'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect { "lib/$it.name" }.join(' '),
                'Implementation-Version': version
    }

    from(configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) })
}
```

Comment: This looks like your app hasn't bundled the dependency along with it. Or it might be a classpath problem. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13372936/2112089 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/14143815/2112089.

Comment: @Pascal could you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pack your libraries with your app to make it runnable and have all dependencies needed on runtime. In example in your build.gradle

As well looking into your code I have a feeling that you don't follow the src/main/java structure, therefore gradle doesn't know where to get the source files from as the default is src/main/java. you can amend SourceSets but I suggest to just follow the structure convention.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
targetCompatibility = 1.5

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34'
    compile 'commons-dbutils:commons-dbutils:1.6'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.4'
    compile 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.10'
    compile 'net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}

jar {
    archiveName = 'Harmonogramy.jar'

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'Main',
                'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect { "lib/$it.name" }.join(' '),
                'Implementation-Version': version
    }
    from(configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) })
}
```

the jar task will extend the default gradle task to build a jar, and will pack all your compile dependencies within - remember to point your main class out to make it executable.

Or you can try to use a shadow plugin found here
https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow

Comment: I did what you said but it doesn't work I edited my post maybe I did something wring

Comment: attributes 'Main-Class': 'Path to your main' is the Reference to your Main class with your main method. archiveName is the name of the jar is being build by gradle. and take the exclude out if you dotn want to exclude anything . i will update my answer for you.

Comment: This is my Main full Main.class : https://paste.ofcode.org/kNuxJAiqneJqQ2FVLDQath and I edit my post. I think I did what you said but it doesn't work

Comment: I have just tested it and all works like a charm. I hope you are running it with  java -jar name.jar in your app dir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136471/discussion-between-krystian-k-and-krzysztof-pokrywka).

Answer (score 0):

The console application needs access to the itext jar at runtime. IntelliJ supplies this dependency automatically, but if you run the code from a console, it's up to you to supply the dependency.

You have two main choices

- start the program with `java -cp <path/to/itext.jar> yourprogram`
- build a "fat jar" using gradle  and run that ( the fat jar bundles your code and all its dependencies in to a single executeable jar file )

Comment: How I can build a "fat .jar" ?

Comment: And when I do this :  java -cp D:\itextpdf-5.3.4.jar Schedule.jar in console I have Error: could not find or load main class Schedule.jar

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka : OK - hadn't realised you were running your program from a jar -that makes life a bit harder. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871656/using-gradle-to-build-a-jar-with-dependencies which may help you building the fat ( or Uber ) jar

Comment: I look their and I don't have idea how I can build a fat jar or run this jar

Comment: add your grade file to your question